# Desarrollo de app/extensión usando Trimble Access SDK

Tags: c++, aplicación-web, sdk

Mi pregunta es más que todo a base de información:

Resulta que trabajo en una empresa de topografía en el desarrollo de aplicaciones web. Tengo un programa (Trimble Access) al cual tengo que hacerle una opción dentro de la aplicación para que cuando el topógrafo vaya a ingresar los datos, los ingrese por medio de imágenes y no por texto.

Ejemplo: Que el menú de opciones en vez de escribir "árbol" aparezca la imagen de un árbol.

¿Es esto posible? o ¿Hacer esta extensión en Python, por ejemplo, Sabiendo que el código original está en C++?

El desarrollo se supone que ha de ser en Visual Studio

Comment: Hola Melissa, No es muy clara para mi la pregunta pues no conozco nada de Trimble Access, pero lo que pude encontrar de manera rápida es que ellos mismos ofrecen un SDK para extensiones, así que **creería** que es posible (https://geospatial.trimble.com/sites/default/files/2017-06/TASDK%20FAQ.pdf). Por otro lado, tu pregunta específica es si se puede cambiar un campo de seleccion de items por texto a seleccion por imagenes? (Algo así como el `<select>` de HTML)?

Comment: Bienvenida Melissa Calle a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..